# Event of dynamically added control is not fired

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

Event of dynamically added control is not fired. This happens in a function called in the create child controls event of the page.

```
Button bb = new Button();
bb.Click += new EventHandler(bb_Click);
PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(bb);
```

Comment: the weird thing that it worked well in another page, but when i copied it and used in another page with some modification its not working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net pages have a [lifecyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Event dispatching is done based on control tree. Your dynamic control should be in in the control tree. Add the control to the placeholder in OnInit or Onload of you page or containing control and the event will be dispatched.

Comment: the weird thing that it worked well in another page, but when i copied it and used in another page with some modification its not working!!

Comment: Hmm. Check the property AutoEventWireUp="True|False" of your page. Maybe it is different set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in an earlier event. Try putting the code in the init event handler.

Comment: the weird thing that it worked well in another page, but when i copied it and used in another page with some modification its not working!!

Comment: put it at the init but it still didnt fire

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that this button is also dynamically created on *each* Page_Load.  I often make the mistake of putting similar code inside of:

```
If Not Page.IsPostback()
  ...
End if
```

However since Page_Load fires *before* the handler for the button click, if you fail to create the button during a postback then the button does not 'exist' by the the time its event fires.

Comment: i put it in the Page_Init and had this if condition but still not working

Comment: No, you specifically want to put it _outside_ of this If condition.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the code in an earlier event wont solve the problem.
Even if you try to put your code in Page_Load() wont solve the problem.

According to the page's life cycle try to override the OnLoad function and recreate and re-wire up your dynamically created controls with the same IDs.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Button bb = new Button() { ID = "myBtn" }
    bb.Click += new EventHandler(bb_Click);
    PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(bb);

    base.OnLoad(e);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```